# .Net Regular Expression to validate a string to match addition of digits

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I need some help in finding how to write a validation expression to validate a string representing addition of digits.

e.g:

> 2 OK
> 2 + 3 OK
> 2+3 not OK
> 2 +3 not OK
> 2 + 3 + 4 OK
>   2 + 3 + not OK
> 2 + 3+ 4 not OK

Answer (score 7):

This should do it:

```
[0-9]( \+ [0-9])+
```

**edit:**

Better yet, for multiple digits per number:

```
[0-9]+( \+ [0-9]+)+
```